# Change color of a tag children on hover of parent element

Tags: html, css

I try to change the color of my `a` tag from red to black on hover over its parent `li`.

```css
.header {
  background-color: black;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.header_links {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.header_links li a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header_links li * {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.header_links li {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.header_links li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.header_links li i {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="header_links">
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url('/start') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-compass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div>Menue</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url('/start') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-compass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div>Test</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried it like this:

```
.header_links li:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color: white;
     color: black;
 }
```

But this won't affect the a tag color at all.

I also tried to make use of important:

```
.header_links li:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color: white;
     color: black !important;
 }
```

But this does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new selector `.header_links li:hover a`

```css
.header {
  background-color: black;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.header_links {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.header_links li a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header_links li * {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.header_links li {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.header_links li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
}

.header_links li:hover a {
  color: black;
}

.header_links li i {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="header_links">
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url('/start') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-compass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div>Menue</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url('/start') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-compass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div>Test</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to target the A tag if you want to change it. 
So change

```
.header_links li:hover {
color: black;
}
```

to

```
.header_links li a:hover {
color: black;
}
```

if you don't want the add the hover to the a tag you can also do this

```
.header_links li:hover a{
   color: black;
}
```

Comment: But I want the whole button background to get white, not only the link part. The while `li` should get a background-color of white and the text should be black.

Comment: i updated my code, you can also just append the a after your li:hover. (but in the future it would be wise to just give padding to your link element, because you want the whole area to be clickable. not only the word.  If you do that the first solution is better

Comment: Hmm thats true, but I cant wrap my `li` into an `a` tag, isnt it?
EDIT: Ok just tried it, it is possible to wrap an `li` with an a tag like this:  `<a><li></li></a>`

Comment: yeah thats possible or just move your padding to header_links li a , both work and both give the user a better experience :)